# php paths that work on both local (mac) and remote server

Tags: php, path

I'm testing a website on my local machine and I'm wondering what would be the best way to write paths to make sure they work when I upload the site to its final location.

In general I'm a bit confused about paths, and in many cases I have to 'tweak' each path until it works, so wouldn't want to be forced to do the same on a production site!

I'm not clear when to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.
For example, I have a directory that I want to scan, which is just under the root. So why can't I just use "/dirname"?

```
$dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/uploads'; //this works
// $dir = "/uploads"; //this doesn't work

if (is_dir($dir)) {
  //do something..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not clear when to use
>   `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. For
>   example, I have a directory that I
>   want to scan, which is just under the
>   root. So why can't I just use
>   "/dirname"?

When you work with paths in the php file the root (`/`) is the root of the filesystem, not the root you get when you visit your website.

So `$dir = "/uploads";` gives you the filesystem root.

To minify your problems I would declare a variable in a configuration file that specifies the root of your php application, and use that path+whatever more is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As adamse mentioned, the reason you can't use the '/path' is because it points to the root of the filesystem.

However, instead of declaring a variable that defines the root, I recommend using `dirname(__FILE__)` to retrieve the full path to the directory that the calling file is in.

From there, append relative path information to the file you want and you end up with a complete path, fully dynamically.

For example, if you want to include the 'header.php' file in the directory above the file that you wish to include it in use:
`include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../header.php');`

The beauty of that is that PHP will always automatically convert the forward slash to the directory separator required for the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a variable/constant that describes the absolute filesystem path to the application. Something like this:

```
$appDir = rtrim(str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))), '/');
```

Then you have this base path you can address your application’s files from:

```
include $appDir.'/library/foo/bar.php';
```

Or you even change your include path to that directory:

```
set_include_path($appDir);
```